# Rebalance BST in O(n) instead of O(nlogn)

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am implementing a BST.
Now I want to rebalance my tree. I already made an implementation which can be done in O(nlogn), but when I googled a bit, I found that it was possible in O(n), but I couldn't find how. This is my code:

Now the method isBalanced() takes O(n) time and checkes wether my tree is balanced or not. I could remove the statement, but the method toArrayList() also takes O(n) time. This method gives me an arraylist with all the nodes from the tree sorted from lowest to highest.

So if I calculate my complexity with the master method, I get O(nlogn) as complexity. I really have no idea how to implement it without using an arraylist/array. I already checked the Day-stout-warren algorithm, but i don't get it :)

Comment: That code looks like it runs in linear time. Are you sure it's O(n log n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm has linear time complexity. The recurrence relation is `T(n) = 2 * T(n / 2) + O(1)`, so `T(n) = O(n)`.

Comment: But when I want to get my arraylist, it takes O(n), so isn't my recurrence relation than `T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + O(n)`?

Comment: Yes I know, but i meant `List<Key> sortedlist = toArrayList();`. This takes O(n) time. But I think I get it now, because that method isn't part of the reccurence relation, I don't have to count it in the master method.

Comment: @Eques Yes, `toArrayList` is called only once.